# WooCommerce - Change the shop page layout but keep the archive-product.php

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am new to WooCommerce and I am trying to build a shop using my custom theme created from scratch. The home page is a static page (custom template) just giving details about the shop . I created a folder in my themes folder named woocommerce and copied the template files. So, I want to keep the archive-product.php but I need to change the layout of the basic shop page. I want it to show the categories and subcategories of the products and some featured products with no prices and add to cart stuff. Which way do you suggest? 
I thought of something which currently works but I don't know if it will cause any issues later. I edited the archive-product.php like this:

```
<?php 
$shop_url = "$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$shop_end = "/shop/";
function endsWith($haystack, $needle) {
    $length = strlen($needle);
    if ($length == 0) {
        return true;
    }
    return (substr($haystack, -$length) === $needle);
}
if (!endsWith($shop_url, $shop_end)) { 
?> 
    archive-product.php stuff 
<?php } else { ?>
    custom shop basic page stuff
<?php } ?>
```

I check if the url ends to '/shop/'...So the code of archive-product.php is used according to url. Is this ok or not? Is there any other safer way to achieve this?
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: WooCommerce provide [`is_shop()`](http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/function-is_shop.html) function to check whether current page is shop page or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [`taxonomy-product_cat.php`](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/taxonomy-product_cat.php#L16) and [`taxonomy-product_tag.php`](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/taxonomy-product_tag.php#L16) templates and you will see that they both call the `archive-product.php` template.

```
wc_get_template( 'archive-product.php' );
```

Therefore, if you wish to change the shop archive, but *not* the taxonomy archives you need to duplicate the `archive-product.php` to another file... say: `archive-product-alt.php` and change the taxonomy templates to call this file instead.

```
wc_get_template( 'archive-product-alt.php' );
```

*Or*, alternatively, you could just copy the contents of `archive-product.php` into `taxonomy-product_cat.php`.